# What should be included in equals and hashcode for JPA Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

In terms of creating a JPA Entity what should and should not go into a equals and hashcode. As an example I have an Address entity as follows.

I've read that the ID should not be included, but not sure why. What about nested objects like State in my case? I did not include locations because State is the non owning end, Location owns the relationship.

Of the following class what should and should not be in the equals and hashcode?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_ADDRESS")
@XmlRootElement
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"id", "locations"})
@ToString(exclude = {"location"})
public class Address implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "addressSeq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "addressSeq", sequenceName = "T_ADDRESS_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "STREET_LINE_1")
    private String streetLine1;

    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "STREET_LINE_2")
    private String streetLine2;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "CITY")
    private String city;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "STATE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private State state;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 10)
    @Column(name = "POSTAL_CODE")
    private String postalCode;

    // Referenced Properties
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "address")
    private List<Location> locations;

    public Address() {
    }

    public Address(String streetLine1, String streetLine2, String city, State state, String postalCode) {
        this.streetLine1 = streetLine1;
        this.streetLine2 = streetLine2;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
        this.postalCode = postalCode;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getStreetLine1() {
        return streetLine1;
    }

    public void setStreetLine1(String streetLine1) {
        this.streetLine1 = streetLine1;
    }

    public String getStreetLine2() {
        return streetLine2;
    }

    public void setStreetLine2(String streetLine2) {
        this.streetLine2 = streetLine2;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public State getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(State state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getPostalCode() {
        return postalCode;
    }

    public void setPostalCode(String postalCode) {
        this.postalCode = postalCode;
    }

    public List<Location> getLocations() {
        return locations;
    }

    public void setLocations(List<Location> locations) {
        this.locations = locations;
    }
}
```

Comment: We can't answer that for you. This highly depends on your business requirement. When do _you_ consider two addresses to be equal, not in terms of code but in terms of your business application? Is it same location? Or maybe same street line?

Comment: In this case if the streetLine1, streetLine2, city,state,and postalCode match then the address would be the same, the database "SHOULD" not be storing duplicate addresses so Id would not be important, but ID is the unique identifier in the table so maybe it should be included. That is where I am kind of scratching my head

Comment: Then you just answered your question: streetLine1, streetLine2, city,state,and postalCode should be tested in equals method. Let the DB manages the ID, you just worry about your business requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommendation I have seen most is that equality for entities should reflect the appropriate sense of equality for your business logic, as opposed to your persistence logic.  If you are using surrogate IDs rather than natural IDs, as is normal with JPA, then that means that you do *not* base entities' equality on their IDs.

Consider: suppose you load an `Address` entity from the database, and you also construct one based on data provided via the application UI.  If you want there to be any possibility that they test as `equals()` each other, then you must base that test only on properties *other than* the ID, because the latter object does not yet have any ID assigned.  It's up to you which properties should contribute to that test.

Of course, if ever you override `equals()` then you should override `hashCode()` as well to ensure the invariant that any two objects that test `equals()` each other have the same hash code.  To do so, you may use only properties that contribute to the equality test in the hash code computation, and for the most distinguishing hash code you should use all such properties.

Note that where an entity has an association with one or more other entities, the IDs of the *other* entities may reasonably factor into the equality test.  For example, your `Address` entity might include the ID of its associated `State` entity in its `equals()` and `hashCode()` determinations.

Comment: This is a very good answer and thorough explanation.

Comment: In my opinion, equals method should reflect the primary key, whether it is simple or compound. If it is not so, you should consider using compound key instead of simple ID key. If your equals method and primary keys are not in line, you may come to **undesired behavior using sets or maps** within your entities, especially if another process may modify the underlying DB and so bypass equality checks in the entities. You must, however, consider instances, which are not yet persisted and **do not have an ID** assigned yet. For these, you may fallback to calling super.equals().

Comment: @OndrejM, certainly there are arguments to be made for basing entity equality on IDs, though I do not personally favor them.  The worst possible thing you can do, however, is to make `equals()` inconsistent or asymmetric, which is what would result from any implementation I can come up with of fallback behavior for certain ID values.

Comment: @John Bollinger: I suggested fallback only when no ID is defined yet - an entity is not yet persisted - therefore it cannot be compared by id. It is most probably a new entity completely different from any other entity and the contract of equals is kept. Having equals to compare data fields of an entity is also not stable if you use it as a hash key or in sets, as hashes should be unmodifiable. By far the best solution is to ensure id is assigned right when an entity is created, but this may be inefficient is certain cases

Comment: @OndrejM, I understood the conditions that you proposed for falling back.  I reiterate that I think such behavior is a *terrible* idea under any circumstances.  I do also understand the arguments on both sides of the question of basing equality on ID vs. basing it on properties.  I acknowledge that both sides have merit, and that thoughtful people may disagree about which side to prefer, whether in general or in specific cases.  I do not intend to debate that issue here, but of course you are welcome to post your own answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your "business" rule. Two instances of Address are equivalent if :

- address1.streetline = address2.streetline
- and address1.city = address2.city
- and address1.postalcode = address2.postalcode
- and address1.state = address2.state

(for instance, maybe you need to include streetline2 too)

You can also change the way to write equals() and hashcode() methods by creating a new attribute state_id. It will contain the state identifier without fetching "State" entity:

```
@Column(name="STATE_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Long stateId;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "STATE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
private State state;
```